# how to define new bullet in ms-word via interop in C#

Tags: c#, ms-word, interop, office-interop

I want to set one of the winidings 3 bullet in msword. in word we can set with define new bullet->symbol->windings 3 but interop how set this type of bullet. can explain with code sample if u know.

i did default bullet with this code

```
oWord.Selection.Range.ListFormat.ApplyBulletDefault(ref objMissing);
```

Thanks,
GOBINATH

Comment: What have you tried so far? Adding code to the post increases the chance for answers

Comment: i set default bullet upto now using oWord.Selection.Range.ListFormat.ApplyBulletDefault(ref objMissing);

Comment: Edit your question and add the code snippet there. If the paragraphs are already formatted with bullet, calling `ApplyBulletDefault` will remove the formatting.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `ListFormat.ApplyListTemplate` method to change the bullet type.

See [this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/9c2879ed-2880-4c34-b94a-deae151eb96f/microsoftofficeinteropword-change-bullet-style?forum=vsto) MSDN forum post for example.